# Moving RelativeLayout with Touch event listener makes the Layout Wiggle while moving

Tags: java, android

I am trying to move a RelativeLayout view around using theTouch Listener.

The problem is that While the Layout is indeed moving it is wiggeling fast between to positions.
This is the full touch listener

```
    protected void touch(){
    Mover manmove = new Mover();

   Wall.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           final int action = motionEvent.getAction();
           if(!isZooming()){

           switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
               //If The Screen is Tapped
               case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
               case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                   //Setting the initial Touch point
                   setTouchDownX(motionEvent.getX());
                   setTouchDownY(motionEvent.getY());

                   break;

               case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):


                       float my = getaY() + (motionEvent.getY() - getTouchDownY());
                       console.log(my);

                      // manmove.moveY(my);



                   break;

           }

           }


           return true;
       }

    });

 }
```

I have created a Console class that logs info to my console.

the manmove.moveY(my)code is at the bottom.

if I (as done above) comment out the manmove.moveY(), as in dont run the method. Console.log outputs the following (Which are the desired coordinates).

```
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/Console(Float):: 0.0
I/Console(Float):: 0.0
I/Console(Float):: -9.876221
I/Console(Float):: -22.249512
I/Console(Float):: -39.085938
I/Console(Float):: -58.50659
I/Console(Float):: -82.34204
I/Console(Float):: -101.75574
I/Console(Float):: -122.02234
I/Console(Float):: -141.76233
I/Console(Float):: -159.39001
I/Console(Float):: -174.78223
I/Console(Float):: -189.00647
I/Console(Float):: -202.30786
I/Console(Float):: -215.42957
I/Console(Float):: -229.95398
I/Console(Float):: -244.98132
I/Console(Float):: -258.14148
I/Console(Float):: -272.5271
```

As you can see they are sequential, so the move should be smooth.
but if I run manmove.moveY(my)

```
                       else{
                       //Allow Scrolling on FullView
                       float my = getaY() + (motionEvent.getY() - getTouchDownY());
                       console.log(my);

                       manmove.moveY(my);


                   }
```

I get this Output;

```
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/Console(Float):: 0.0
I/Console(Float):: 0.0
I/Console(Float):: 0.0
I/Console(Float):: -7.222168
I/Console(Float):: -86.498535
I/Console(Float):: -60.04187
I/Console(Float):: -125.71619
I/Console(Float):: -92.756226
I/Console(Float):: -152.55365
I/Console(Float):: -113.45459
I/Console(Float):: -178.72412
I/Console(Float):: -140.0473
I/Console(Float):: -206.31036
I/Console(Float):: -170.90485
I/Console(Float):: -222.82135
I/Console(Float):: -188.71191
I/Console(Float):: -234.86389
```

As you can see the output isnt in order. As if there are two different events happening. Why am I getting this result by just running the below method

(Wall by the way is a RelativeLayout)

Here's the moveY(my) method

```
public class Mover extends Brain {
public Mover(){

}

public void moveX(float val){


   Wall.setX(val);

}
public void moveY(float val){

    Wall.setY(val);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys forget about it I solved it.

All I had to do is setaY(my) to update the new position.

```
        float my = getaY() + (motionEvent.getY() - getTouchDownY());
                       console.log(my);

                       manmove.moveY(my);
                       setaX(my);
```